# How to install Gambas programming IDE on mac mini?

Tags: gambas

How to install Gambas programming IDE on mac mini?

https://gambas.sourceforge.net/en/main.html

I went through the `https://gambaswiki.org/wiki/install` as well but I don't get what to do. Downloaded the package which is in a zip format. Unzipped. It has a file named "install" and it just shows a link to `https://gambaswiki.org/wiki/install` Now what?

Any terminal command on macOs?

Comment: All of the install instructions are for Linux; all involve compilation.  No pre-built binaries; no specific instructions for Windows or MacOS.  I'm sure you probably *CAN* run Gambas on a Mac.  But if you're not comfortable with "make", "C++" and so on ... perhaps you might want to consider another, different IDE?

Comment: @paulsm4 any different IDE similar to gambas? I was coding with C++ as well. Every language is very similar anyways. I just need to have this as I liked the visualbasic software.

Comment: XCode is the most common IDE for MacOS.  Visual Studio Code might be another good option.  There are many, many alternatives, depending on exactly what you want to do, and your personal preferences.  PS: "Every language is very similar" ?!?  Das stimmt einfach nicht ;)

Comment: @paulsm4 The main thing is I want my program to run on multi-platforms. I want it to run on macOS, windows and linux. I hate XCode, it's easy to use, but I don't like it. Even the flutter by google, more I learn to do things with ease in those software, I start to hate them. I've been through many IDEs and languages. C++, and visual basic was the things I still like. I don't like windows OS, but really like the macOS. So I wanted something similar to VB IDE which can run in the macOS. And I still believe every language is very similar to each other.